# How do I use firewall-cmd to block all outbound connections but exclude an IP number and also allow all inbound connections?

Tags: centos, network-interface, acl, firewalld

I have 1 server using CentOS7:

- Local subnet: `192.168.10.10/24 => interface eth0`
- WAN subnet: `123.456.879/22 => interface eth1`

I want to use `firewall-cmd` to block all outbound connections from the local subnet, but it can still connect to `192.168.10.20` and `192.168.10.30`.

At the same time, all incoming connections from the local subnet still connect to `192.168.10.10` as usual.

I use the command as below:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j REJECT
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -d 192.168.10.20 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -d 192.168.10.30 -j ACCEPT
```

10.10 cannot connect to 10.20 and 10.30, and other servers cannot connect to 10.10. I did something wrong, please help me find the cause

Comment: if you mean that you want to stop the hosts in 192.168.10.10/24 from reaching the WAN completely, then you don't even need firewall rules, just disable routing (or `iptables -F FORWARD; iptables -P FORWARD DROP` if you like)

Comment: if that's not what you mean, then you need to define "blocking all outbound connections from the local subnet" more clearly. Do you mean traffic originating from that CentOS server itself? Or traffic originating from other hosts in 192.168.10.10/24? And what does "outbound" mean? To the WAN, or to anywhere outside that host?

Comment: @ilkkachu Exactly what I want is on the local network, in the Outgoing host 192.168.10.10 can only connect to 192.168.10.20 and 192.168.10.30. In the Ingoing, all hosts in the range 192.168.10.0/24 connect to 192.168.10.10 as always. All conditions do not affect the WAN line.